# "go back" function for the page

Tags: javascript, html, browser

I am unable to understand how to implement the "go back" function for the page.

For example, i have A,B,C,D pages. Between the pages possible switching:
A -> (B <-> C) -> A or D -> ( B<->C ) -> D (A - catalog, B - product description, C - product order, D - cart). The switch B <-> C can be an unlimited number of times, but "go back" function must switch to start point page (A or D). The page B or/and C can be opened in different tabs at the same time, from different start points (A or D).

Using path cookies or localstorage? Items are global for all browser tabs.

Using URL parameter? It is unnecessary information in URL.

Using URL with `back-url` parameter and redirect to page without him (url without parameter, but with link inside page). One redirect for every B or C page.

Are there other ways of solving the problem (client or server side)?

Comment: [history.pushState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history)

Comment: What is wrong with using the browers history..  `window.history.back();`

Comment: A -> B-> C -> back button switch to B, but need A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you can solve your problem by using `location.replace()` on the B and C pages for navigating between them. This has the effect of not saving the current page in the sessions history, so that clicking back returns the user to whichever page she was on before B or C.

You can [read more about replace here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location.replace).

Comment: Yes, you understand my question correctly. No history - no problem. Native back button will work how i want. And no other "back links" on the page.

Comment: How about POST request on page "C" (request with form)? How to skip saving him to history?

Comment: Maybe you can submit the form with AJAX?

Comment: I think this is the only way